# VBS access select into txt

Tags: vbscript, ms-access-2010

I want to write a access sql into a txt file via vbs. The script is working fine, besides I didn't get any output.

```
    Call OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Table 1]")

    dbRec.Close:   dbCon.Close

   'WScript.Quit

'Main End


Private Sub OpenRecordset(ByRef dbSql)

    Set dbCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set dbRec = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    With dbCon 'Verbindung zur Datenbank herstellen
        .Mode = adModeReadWrite
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        '.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"  '*.mdb
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" '*.accdb ACCESS 2007
        .Properties("Data Source") = dbPath
        .Properties("Persist Security Info") = False
        .Properties("User ID") = "***"
        .Properties("Password") = "***"
        .Properties("Jet OLEDB:System database") = dbSystem
        .Open
    End With

    With dbRec 'Einen Recordset für die Datensätze erstellen
        .Source = dbSql
        .ActiveConnection = dbCon
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .Open
    End With
End Sub
```

How can I do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856990/exporting-a-parameterized-query-to-excel-using-vba for a similar case

Comment: Did it the following way:

    Set objFSO = Wscript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("path_to_txt", ForWriting, Create)
    
        
       'Datensatz
        Do While Not dbRec.eof
            objFile.WriteLine dbRec.Fields("value1").value & "," &       dbRec.Fields("value2").value & "," & dbRec.Fields("value3").value
            dbRec.MoveNext
        Loop
        objFile.close

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. You could create an answer with the text from your comment, wait some time, and accept it. This gives you some points, and more importantly, the question is closed, ready to help others in a similar situation.